# Should adapter be local variable or instance variable?

Tags: android, adapter

When setting adapter for listView, should I just do `listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapater());` or should I keep the adapter as instance variable and set it to null when onDestory() ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the use case.

1. If you are going to do data manipulation such as rearranging the order of elements or changing the data dynamically in some way, then its "better" to have an instance variable of your adapter. It will safe you from casting your adapter from ListView getAdapter() method, whenever accessing your adapter.
2. If you are creating a simple list view consisted of for ex. 10 Strings and you dont plan on doing anything with the data set, then you don't need to keep a reference to your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to maintain adapter as instance variable because each and every time you have to create new adapter instead of that just change the data and you can call notifyDatasetChanged() so that adapter will be refreshed.

Comment: This is not a true. If you initialised adapter as anonymous instance then you don't need to create each time new instance of it if you need to update dataset. In this case you can simply cast adapter attached into ListView but this "cast" takes cost and time (how i mentioned in my answer bellow).

Comment: if you want to use same adapter in another activity then?

Comment: @Chandrakanth so what? If you want to use same adapter in another activity where is a problem?

Comment: anonymous inner is also instance object. if you want to use same adapter again what you will do?

Comment: @NoName what you mean by "use same adapter again"?

Comment: mr. ragnar if you are using different types of lists but you are using same bean class objects in that scenario you will create new adapter class for that?

Comment: @NoName different type of list in same activity/fragment?

Comment: it may be fragment or activity example contacts application will have two lists with same adapter (contacts and favrts.)